# Using the $cond statement with $project and aggregate in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to project a new field based on a conditional logic statement, using pymongo.

The value should equal 1 if the *'status'* field is either *'successful_ended'* or *'successful_ongoing'*. I've tried implementing this by using `$in` within a `$cond` statement. A simplified version of my aggregate statement is like so:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$project': {'platform':1, 'platform_id':1, 'funding_type':1, 'raised_usd':1, 'status':1, 
                  'successful_1': # an equals statement works
                     {
                        '$cond':[{'$eq':['status', 'successful_ended']}, 1, 0]
                     },
                  'successful_2': # but this fails 
                     {
                        '$cond':[{'status': {'$in': ['successful_ended', 'successful_ongoing']}}, 1, 0]
                     }
                  }
    }
]

result = db.projects.aggregate(pipeline)
```

And it fails with the message:

```
invalid operator '$in'
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: are you sure `$eq` works? you compare with `'status'`, shouldn't it be `'$status'`?

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised by that too! It works both with `status` and `$status`

Comment: are you sure? Because, what would you do if you had a `status` field, but wanted to compare its value against `'status'` string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) operator instead which evaluates one or more expressions and returns true if any of the expressions are true. Otherwise, [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) returns false. Thus the `successful_2` field can be projected as:

```
'successful_2': {
    '$cond': [ 
        { 
            '$or': [ 
                { '$eq': [ '$status', 'successful_ended' ] }, 
                { '$eq': [ '$status', 'successful_ongoing' ] } 
            ]
        }     
        , 1, 0 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `$in` operator defined for the aggregation framework.

As you can see there are separate `$eq` operators defined for a [regular query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) and [aggregation query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/), and their syntax is different.

However `$in` is defined only for a regular query.

If you want to compare a field value against multiple values, you better go with [chridam's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440704/3264192)